# C# Reflection: How to Emit a class

Tags: c#, class, reflection, dll, dynamic

I have a class, ReferenceObject, that I want Emitted into the dll I create.  How do I do this without writing every method with Emit?  I basically want this class added to the dll I generate.

Here is the class:

```
public class ReferenceObject
{
    private readonly int value;

    public ReferenceObject(int pValue)
    {
        value = pValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public int Value()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public int ID()
    {
        return value;
    }

    #region == Operator

    public static bool operator ==(int objLeft, ReferenceObject objRight)
    {
        return objLeft == objRight.value;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ReferenceObject objLeft, int objRight)
    {
        return objLeft.value == objRight;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(string objLeft, ReferenceObject objRight)
    {
        return objLeft == objRight.value.ToString();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ReferenceObject objLeft, string objRight)
    {
        return objLeft.value.ToString() == objRight;
    }

    #endregion

    #region != Operator

    public static bool operator !=(int objLeft, ReferenceObject objRight)
    {
        return objLeft != objRight.value;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ReferenceObject objLeft, int objRight)
    {
        return objLeft.value != objRight;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(string objLeft, ReferenceObject objRight)
    {
        return objLeft != objRight.value.ToString();
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ReferenceObject objLeft, string objRight)
    {
        return objLeft.value.ToString() != objRight;
    }

    #endregion

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj is ReferenceObject))
            return value == ((ReferenceObject)obj).value;

        if ((obj is int))
            return value == (int)obj;

        if ((obj is string))
            return value.ToString() == (string)obj;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is the code I use to generate the .dll

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicEnums");
AssemblyBuilder ab = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

ConstructorInfo referenceObjectConstructor = typeof(ReferenceObject).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });

List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

foreach(ReferenceType rt in GetTypes())
{
    TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(rt.Name, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);

    ConstructorBuilder staticConstructorBuilder = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes);
    ILGenerator staticConstructorILGenerator = staticConstructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    foreach (Reference r in GetReferences(rt.ID))
    {
        name = NameFix(r.Name);

        // Create a public, static, readonly field to store the
        // named ReferenceObject.
        FieldBuilder referenceObjectField = tb.DefineField(name, typeof(ReferenceObject), FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.InitOnly);

        // Add code to the static constructor to populate the
        // ReferenceObject field:

        // Load the ReferenceObject's ID value onto the stack as a
        // literal 4-byte integer (Int32).
        staticConstructorILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, r.ID);

        // Create a reference to a new ReferenceObject on the stack
        // by calling the ReferenceObject(int32 pValue) reference
        // we created earlier.
        staticConstructorILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, referenceObjectConstructor);

        // Store the ReferenceObject reference to the static
        // ReferenceObject field.
        staticConstructorILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, referenceObjectField);
    }
    staticConstructorILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    types.Add(tb.CreateType());
}

ab.Save(aName.Name + ".dll");
```

Comment: I dont understand the purpose. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have some tables in my database.  I want to use them to populate static ReferenceObjects so that I can reference them in code like if (country == Countries.USA).  The rest of the code does it, but I need the ReferenceObject class stuffed in the generated .dll as well.

Comment: Why can't you just reference the DLL in which that class is defined in your new DLL?

Comment: How would you do that with Reflection?  I'm creating a new dll here, if there's a way to reference the other one please show me how!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Reflection.Emit add-in for Reflector:

You can download Reflector here:
http://www.reflector.net/

And here is a link to the add-in:
http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReflectionEmitLanguage&referringTitle=Home

**EDIT**

You might also want to take a look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Creating_Dynamic_Types.aspx

Comment: Is that the only way?  I know I could do this by writing each method out in IL like this crap: 

    staticConstructorILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, r.ID);

I'm looking for some way to tell built in reflection the class definition, .cs file, or .dll file to go get the code I already wrote and add it to the .dll I'm creating.

Answer (score 1):

In response to comment.

Why not just use CodeDom then, or just use or write an 'offline' code generator? Reflection.Emit is only needed when you want to create types at runtime, else it is pretty much overkill.

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/dbhelper.aspx) for an example of what I did years ago.

Comment: I really only need it generated at build time, I suppose.  Does that make a difference?  Pre build, fetch the objects from the database, for each one make a (ReferenceType).(ReferenceName) object of type ReferenceObject.  Perhaps I don't need Reflection.Emit, but I want the dll rebuilt every time I build from any updated db changes.

Comment: @Ehryk: You write a small app to do that as part of the build. Probably the pre-build event.